# How to create simple mp3 file?

Tags: audio, mp3, wav

How to create simple mp3 file? It can be just one tone 440hz playing for one minute for example. I know that there is the specification of mp3 but it's not so obvious and it is easy to do some mistake and receive incorrect format. May be someone already have any example of source code that create such simple mp3 file? Thank you :)

Comment: Do you want to write an encoder from scratch? I'd say this isn't worth the effort (and can't be answered in scope here). Just decide which language you want to use, find a library, read the manual, decide about the encoding parameters, and do it. It's quite some work though.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ?  If you wish to wrote code to synthesize audio then I suggest for starters you output to a wav format which is trivial ... its just dump your raw audio buffer into a binary file where you have attached a 44 byte header ... let us know

Comment: Thank you :) I found what I wanted :) http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/109119/